# How can I execute javascript code every a specific time interval?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to ping the server every 2 minutes using jQuery. I thought about an open loop with setTimeout function but I think this would crush the browser - any suggestions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use setTimeout() for this type of action, rather use setInterval().

```
var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    /* Do your magic */
}, 2000);
```

To clear your interval, simply `clearInterval(intervalId)`, when you wish to stop the ping:ing.